# How do i select a div by its key? reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Here I have this div that is generated dynamically by data its parent component receives:

```
            {Object.keys(this.state.cart.cart).map((key,i)=>{
                return(
                                <div className="item" key={i} identifier="mat">
                                    <div className="carti">
                                        <input type="number" value={this.state.cart.cart[key].quantity} min="1"/>
                                        <h4 className="generalDescription">{key}</h4>
                                        <h4 className="cost">₦{Math.round(this.state.cart.cart[key].totalCost*100)/100}</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <a className="cancelBtn" key={i} onClick={this.deleteDiv} >x</a>
                                </div>)

            })}
```

I have this function that is called by the onClick event handler:

```
deleteDiv(e){
        console.log(e.target.key);
    }
```

Now I want to get the value of the key when ever i click the X button, but what I get on the console is undefined.I need help!

Comment: The key isn't an actual prop that shows up on elements once they're inserted into the DOM, it's something used by React internally for child lookup and updating...

Comment: so whats the way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Andrew suggested, `key` is a prop and doesn't translate to an attribute for the corresponding node in the DOM. If you want to access it, you could either pass it to the function with something like:

```
deleteDiv(index){
  console.log(index);
}
...
<a className="cancelBtn" key={i} onClick={this.deleteDiv.bind(i)}>x</a>
//or
<a className="cancelBtn" key={i} onClick={() => this.deleteDiv(i)}>x</a>
```

or even:

```
deleteDiv(e){
  console.log(e.target.dataset.key);
}
<a className="cancelBtn" key={i} data-key={i} onClick={this.deleteDiv}>x</a>
```

Comment: when i make the key={key} i get undefined in the console...what did i do wrong?

Comment: You did `key={key}`? I don't know, did you try my solution? I don't do `key={key}`... Which of the 2 solutions are you trying above?

Comment: i tried your solution and it worked...what is "data-key={i}" ?

Comment: @JohnAnisere Here is what the MDN says *"HTML5 is designed with extensibility in mind for data that should be associated with a particular element but need not have any defined meaning. data-\* attributes allow us to store extra information on standard, semantic HTML elements"*. So basically anything starting with `data-` will be given to the related dom-node. When you click on the item, the triggered function gets an event parameter `e`, right? Well, `e.target` is actually a reference to the dom-node you clicked on, you can then read these `data-` attributes as shown above.

Comment: Thank you bruh. I really appreciate this

Answer (score 0):

If all you need an index in event handler, just pass it into function as the argument:

```html
<a className="cancelBtn" key={i} onClick={() => this.deleteDiv(i)}>x</a>
```

And then

```javascript
deleteDiv(index) {
    console.log(index);
}
```